# 3 normals to a parabola

Tags: analytic-geometry

> What is the least value of $z$ such that 3 normals from $P(z,0)$ can be drawn to $y^2=4ax$?

I thought that any point inside the parabola should satisfy this condition but I was proven wrong.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475698/condition-on-a-point-on-axis-of-the-parabola-so-that-3-distinct-normals-can-be  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601215/finding-the-number-of-normals-to-a-parabola

Comment: Ty very much 4 this link #lab bhattacharjee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint...write down the equation of the normal at $(at^2,2at)$ and plug in $x=z,y=0$

The resulting equation in $t$ must have three distinct roots (one of which is zero).